# Angular - how to link from one page to another page and scroll to an anchor in ionic without using id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an **ionic** app. Which has a listing of articles on my home page, and each article has a comment icon which should serve as a link to comment section in the article page.

How can I link from that front page to go to an anchor on the comment section in the article page?

**Updated**

Since Angular uses "URLs" after the # , it won't work to link to an anchor by id, that was suggested in the answer, so I am looking for another way to do it. 
I have tried several solutions but none of the following didn't work.

Here, sometimes I get a correct value for top offset, but when I change to another article page, the value stays the same.

This is the code I have done:

Article list View:

```
<a ng-click="commentLink({{article.id}})">
              <img class="social-images" src="icons/comment.svg"/> {{ article.comments.length }}
            </a>
```

Article View:

```
<a name="comments-section"></a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.commentLink = function(articleId) {
    return $state.go('main.article', {id: articleId}).then(function(state) {
      var position = $ionicPosition.offset(angular.element(document.getElementsByName('comments-section')));
      console.log(position.top);
      $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);
    })
  };
```

I have also tried this, based on an this [article](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/anchor-scrolling-in-ionic-framework-angularjs-e2c19d7aa668#.45u408rhp), but still no luck:

Controller:

```
$location.hash('comments-section');
  var handle = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('articleDelegate');
  handle.anchorScroll(true);
```

View:

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="articleDelegate">

<a id="comments-section"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your comment section has an id (eg. id="new-comment"), then from the front page, you can try:

```
<a ng-click="goToComment()">...</a>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.goToComment = function() {
  return $state.go('whatever the comment state is',           {param:param}).then(function(state) {
    $location.hash('new-comment');
    $ionicScrollDelegate.anchorScroll(true)
  })
 }
```

Comment: I just tested it and it seems like it is not working the first time you click it, and it also seems like it is not refreshing or like it is remembering the state, because when it starts working then when I click the normal link, after I have already entered the page previously with anchor link, it seems to remember that and opens the page on that anchor and url has that hash.  @Ladmerc